# Select specific fields from MySQL table based on variable in PHP/CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

Just wondering about how to best achieve the following in CodeIgniter with Active Record:

```
$language = 'nl'; // or 'en', 'sp', etc.
$this->db->select('id, description_'.$language.' as description, some_more_fields');
$q = $this->db->get('table_name');
```

If I use it like this the `$q` won't be a proper database result object and i'll get fatal errors later when using it:

```
PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in /somescript.php on line 12345
```

Also, the `$language` variable is derived from user-input, so should imo be properly escaped..

Thank you!

Comment: _"ACTIVE RECORD"_ Codeigniter doesn't have active record. just pointing it out.

Comment: @itachi : CI doesn't have "*ACTIVE RECORD*"??? Then what is [**ACTIVE RECORD CLASS**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Comment: @elavarasanlee that's `query builder`. not active record.

Comment: well, it might be query builder, but it's called "active record class", so we refer to it as active record so we all know what we're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

You're quoting it wrong,

```
$this->db->select('id, description_'.$language.' as description, some_more_fields');
```

Comment: Ah yes, i'm sorry + thanks. In my code it has these .'s, missed this while typing the question. Won't resolve the problem however.

Comment: Check your error using `$this->db->_error_message();`.

Answer (score 1):

$q will be an array of objects, thus used like this:

```
foreach ($q->result() as $row)
    {
       echo $row->id;
       echo $row->description;
       echo $row->some_more_fields;
    }
```

(http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)